# XlsxWriter: Generate multi-worksheet workbook from separate python files?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am writing a python script using *XlsxWriter* to generate an .xlsx file comprising of multiple worksheets. Each worksheet will have multiple tables and lots of formatting - hence my code is getting pretty long. Therefore, I am looking for a way to split the code up, eg. Worksheet 1 corresponding to worksheet1.py,  with a 'main' file to compile the worksheets into a single workbook.

I have tried using a function to create a worksheet and calling that from another file to add to an existing workbook - but this method does not work. XlsxWriter requires you to add the worksheet to an existing workbook. (If I'm missing something and this is possible please let me know).

Alternately, I thought of creating individual workbooks with a single worksheet inside and using a second package (openpyxl) to collate the worksheets. However, I think this will alter the formatting on the worksheets. (Again, please let me know if I am missing something).

Any ideas on this subject would be greatly received

Thanks

Edit: example table

[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAhiH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will actually be very helpful in this case.
you can first create writer for your excel file

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
```

create you tables are dataframe, [check here about dataframes basics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_dataframe.htm)

```
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet  1',startrow=0 , startcol=0)
```

place that table easily into any excel sheet(workbook) you want just provide the name as argument.
put another table in same sheet

```
df_1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet  1',startrow=20 , startcol=0)
```

change the row from where you want to start the table, or change the sheet name

Comment: Thanks for this reply. However, I don't think that quite solves my problem. The tables I'm looking to add have quite a lot of formatting (see image in edited post), so I don't think pasting a dataframe would get the outcome I'm looking for. I'm creating them by looping over my original dataset and using 'worksheet.write' to add them in, hence why I'm looking to add the worksheet as a whole.